# Trying to print a single line of a table using BeautifulSoup, but the line location keeps changing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to get a table row to print out using BeautifulSoup, but I can't just use the ID of the row because the location of the row can change depending on a couple different variables. The rows all have names like `trRow_1`. What I need it to do is to print out the row that contains the text I'm looking for since it moves.

I cannot figure out the wording for me to print out the desired line using `if` statements.

This is what I've tried, which obviously doesn't work but should give you the idea of what I want:

```
table = soup1.find("table", id="tblActivities")
tablerow = table.findAll("tr")
TextIwant = tablerow.find(<span>"The Text I Want"</span>)
print(TextIWant)
```

Any idea of how to do this?

This is the row element I'm working with:

```
<tr id="trRow_5" class="changeTrOnhover" uniqueid="" rowid="2200005" action="0" postype="0" levelclass="2200005" riskcountry="United States" issuecurrency="" riskregion="" seq="5">

                     <!-- End positionDetail greater than 0 -->  


                        <td>





                                        <span class="bold"> Cash Equivalent

                            </span>
                        </td>  <!-- Asset class desc -->


                        <td><span></span></td>      <!-- price -->
                        <td><span></span></td>       <!-- quantity -->
                        <!-- START PSI19 US77980 Populate values for Investment cost -->

                            <td class="bold"><span>
                                <span>52,896.91 USD
                            </span></span></td>

                        <!-- END PSI19 US77980 Populate values for Investment cost -->
                        <!-- base mkt -->

                        <td class="bold"><span>
                        52,896.91 USD
                        </span></td>

                        <!-- local mkt -->

                        <!-- perc of class -->

                        <td nowrap="">
                            <span class="bold">

                                    6.88

                            </span>
                        </td>    

                        <!-- perc of total mkt -->

                        <!-- income yield -->

                        <!-- moodys -->


                        <td><span></span></td>     <!-- action -->
                     <!-- positionDetail = 0 -->     
                </tr>
```

```
soup.select_one('table#tblActivities').select('tr:has(td:contains("Cash Equivalent")) td')
```

This returns all of the table rows.

```
for td in table.select('tr:has(td:contains("Cash Equivalent")) td'):
print(td.text.strip())
```

This returns all of the rows in the table as well.

Comment: Can you post a sample of `tablerow`s with and without the target rows?

Comment: I'll try to grab an example in a bit.

Comment: Example added, please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: And what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output is all the content of the row that contains the text "Cash Equivalent" I need to be able to print the text of that line every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is exactly. @Andrej Kesely's solution works for me. A simplified version of his solution also works:

```
soup = bs([your html above],'html5')

for element in soup.select('tr:has(span:contains("Cash Equivalent"))'):
         print(element.text.replace('\n','').strip())
```

And if you change tactics and replace css selection with `find()` methods

```
tab = soup.find('table',id='tblActivities')
row = soup.find(lambda tag:tag.name=="span" and "Cash Equivalent" in tag.text)
for i in row:
    print(i.parent.parent.parent.text.strip().replace('\n',''))
```

That also works. In all these cases, the output is:

> Cash Equivalent
>
> 52,896.91 USD
>
> 52,896.91 USD
>
> 6.88

which, I believe, is what you are looking for.

Comment: The ```find()``` method did work, but the simplified version didn't. Not sure where this is going wrong, but at any rate thank you for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `:has()` and `:contains()` to select row with td that contains selected text:

```
data = '''
<table id="tblActivities">
    <tr>
        <td>I Dont want this</td>
        <td>I Dont want this</td>
        <td>I Dont want this</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Some data</td>
        <td><span>The Text I Want</span></td>
        <td>Some data</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>I Dont want this</td>
        <td>I Dont want this</td>
        <td>I Dont want this</td>
    </tr>
</table>

'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

table = soup.select_one('table#tblActivities')

for td in table.select('tr:has(td:contains("The Text I Want")) td'):
    print(td.text)
```

Prints:

```
Some data
The Text I Want
Some data
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selector reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Comment: This did work in a way, but it printed all the text in the table instead of just the desired row's text.

Comment: @Loons22 Can you edit your question and put there sample of your table - to see what selector will you need.

Comment: Edited my question and added a partial sample of the table, it was 6000 lines so I just added the first 80 or so. Also added the table row that I'm trying to pull above that.

Comment: @Loons22 The example you pasted contains only headers of table, not actual rows. What string are you searching for in this `<tr>`?

Comment: The string I'm searching for in here has the title "Cash Equivalent" I just added what I think the row I'm looking for exactly is. Sorry if it's the wrong thing.

Comment: @Loons22 `soup.select_one('table#tblActivities').select('tr:has(td:contains("Cash Equivalent")) td')` isn´t working?

Comment: I tried both, included what they return in my edit.

Comment: @Loons22 That only means that `"Cash Equivavelent"` must be inside all or majority of rows.